# macro over protected and shared worksheet excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2002

I have a shared and protected worsheet in excel 2012. (protected but without password)
I wrote this macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("B4:K38").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
   'cells I don't want to be protect (to be user-editable)
    Range("B4:K38").Locked = False
   'protecting the sheet, and all the other cells will be protected
    Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

But everytime I use this macro I have a message that shows me that there's an error with the method protect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: You don't need to unprotect to run vba on a sheet if it is protected using userinterfaceonly, that setting is designed so you do not need to unprotect.

Comment: well, what I need is to sort by colomn D4 and the users wont have permission to write anything outside the table that is from B4 to K38.please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested since on mobile

rather than using `protect userinterfaceonly:=true`

```
    with activesheet
         .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells 
         .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True 
    End With
```

Also using UserInterfaceOnly you shouldn't need to unprotect the sheet to edit it with vba.

Comment: doesn't work. 1004 run time error.
how would you do it? think that you have a shared workbook and you want users that share it only can edit some cells. 
I don't know why is too hard to do it !!!! may be I have vba knowledge lack.

Comment: Try the edit if not i'll get to a machine with full excel and try some examples